# CSS Transform DIV without transform child

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I'm trying to centralize a DIV with Transform in CSS, but I have another child inside which was suposed to float in an absolute position:

```css
#container {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.popup {
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
.popuptrigger:focus + .popup {
  display: initial;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <input class="popuptrigger">
  <div class="popup">Something else</div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, popup div are aligning itself at top/left of container div

How can I do this works without javascript or jQuery, i need to be pure CSS

Comment: How exactly do you want the `.popup` to be positioned? What should its point of reference be?

Comment: It is not totally clear what you are trying to achieve - can you elaborate?

Comment: You mean you want "Something else" to be at the top left of the page, rather than in the middle? If it has different behaviour from the `container` you should either not put it inside `container` or position the _other_ elements, i.e. the textbox, centrally, not the whole thing

Comment: Sorry, I forgot one class in the CSS, look again...
I want "Something else" at page's left: 30px top: 30px;

Comment: I need ".popup" to be inside "container" because I'm using that input as a trigger to show/hide .popup

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what information you need to display, you could center the input itself and remove it from the container. You can then provide any other information in the container, making sure not to overlap the input.

#### Example

```css
.popuptrigger {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin-top: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  background: #F00;
  padding: 10px;
}
.popup {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  display: none;
}
input {
  display: block;  
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.popuptrigger:focus + .popup {
  display: initial;
}
```

```html
<input class="popuptrigger" value="firstInput">
<div class="popup">This is the popup text.</div>

<div class="container">
  <input value="second input">
   <input value="third input">
</div>
```

Comment: The container have a complete form, when user enter in two of them that popup will show details about what they have to insert there

Comment: You can position inputs around it. I added an example in my answer. Of course, this would all be easier if the popup was created with javascript :)